# NAS backup no longer working due to time machine stuck preparing backup. Error 19

Tags: macos, time-machine

For about a year my Mac has been backing up to a local NAS drive. A few weeks ago it stopped backing up and when i try and manually start a backup this occurs.

[image]

How do i prevent this happening so i  ay continue to backup my computer?

Cheers.

Comment: Does the NAS have logs you can read or an article or support for how to debug time machine usage?

Comment: Make sure the NAS' firmware is up to date as well as any specific TimeMachine app, if applicable. Also reboot the NAS and verify the filesystem using the NAS software control panel. Once you have done that add it to your question along with the make, model and version of your NAS

Answer (score 1):

I don’t back up to nas so I can’t fix that specific error, but one excellent troubleshooting step you can do is attempt a restore from that volume.

The requirements to restore are fewer than a complete backup.

Next step is to add an external drive and add it as a second destination. See if Time Machine can do a backup to a different clean disk. [It will still continue to try to back up to the nas every other interval](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4987826), but at least you will know the system itself is good and keep backups current while you suss out the cryptic error code.

Lastly, even if you can’t restore from the sparse bundle, can you select it in finder and get it to mount? That will let you know if it needs repair in Disk Utility.

Answer (score 1):

I happened to have the same problem and found a lot of useless hints to solve the issue.

I can assure you 100% it has nothing to do with file permissions, NAS version, NAS filesystem, ... it is 100% an incompatibility a Monterey patch introduced depending on when the disc was **initially** created.

I'm using Synology DS918+ DSM 7.1-42661 Update 4 - which has served as a time machine capsule for years without problems.

Now I'm getting error 19 while still being able to access the files and folders on the NAS without problems via SMB, AFP, SSH,...

Depending on when you initially created your backup disc, it is not compatible anymore with Monterey.

> If you upgraded to macOS Monterey, your existing backups are not
> upgraded. New backups that are created can be used only on macOS Big
> Sur or later.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh15653/mac

Remove the backup disc from Time Machine and create a fresh new one solves the problem.

Comment: Seems this was the case for me. After exhausting every option, creating a fresh backup, instead of attempting to overwrite the old one, worked without a hitch.